# How is Global K/D Ratio worked out in CoD?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-3, call-of-duty-series

<sub>I hope this is on-topic here, I did check but I'm not sure.</sub>

I can't seem to find exactly how ***Global K/D*** is worked out in CoD, specifically BO3. I can only find which game modes it represents and stuff like that.

I assume it is worked out from all kills and all deaths **ever** in public matches, but I can't find this info, so I can't tell for sure.

Maybe it's like the average for the past 100 matches for example?

When I started playing BO3, I was *not very good*, but now I rarely go below a 1.8 K/D ***average***(shown after public match). But my K/D is still below 1.00, so I just wanted to work out roughly how many matches it was going to take to get it above 1.00.

So to summerize,
How is Global K/D worked out exactly?
And is there somewhere I can check my total kills and deaths in public matches since I started playing?

Comment: How long has it been since you first started playing? If it's been a long time and your global K/D is still below 1, I'd say it's likely every kill and death you ever in pub matches. If it were an average of your recent matches, I think it would probably show up as 'Recent K/D' or something similar.

Comment: The Leaderboard shows your stuff for that particular game type and the Barracks show the all time combat record. Also a fresh start resets them (actually everything else too).

Comment: It went up yesterday, 0.94 now! So it _is_ creeping up. if it _is_ all time K/D, it should start creeping faster and faster. I'll check combat record and work it out and maybe add an answer. Global SPM is even worse but that jumped up a point a couple of days ago too.